# Array Initialization

Tags: java

Having two main ways to initialize the elements of an Array in Java. Which would work best Initializer List or For Loop Initialization since when an array is created each element of that array is automatically initialized to the default value. So if you create an array of 20 integers each element has a value of zero. But suppose you want the elements to have a specific value other than zero which one of the two approaches would achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Check Arrays.fill:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29

It may not be the fastest solution (I don't know), but you'll get points for clarity.

Ps It's a useful class in general.

Answer (score 1):

If the values changes, the better way is using a for loop:

```
public int[] getArray(int size) {
    int numbers[] = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        numbers[i] = doSomeCalculation();
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

If you have hard coded values, just initialize it manually:

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list if you do not know the upper bound of your array, i.e. you don't know how many elements the array will contain:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
int[] myArray = myList.toArray(new int[myList.size()]);
```

You may also just consider using a `List` if you don't know the upper bound.

Use an array when you know the upper bound, or you already have the elements:

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2};
int[] myArray = new int[2];
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
```